# Build npm package in Windows pre build in Linux

Tags: linux, node.js, gruntjs, npm, bower

I have a downloaded a project which has been developed and previously build in npm in Linux environment. I want to build and use it in Windows environment. Other than the dependencies shown in the package.json file there were few other dependencies error like bower, grunt etc. which I solved it manually.

I am not able to build and run it.

Can anyone please suggest the steps for building and running the package in Windows environment.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: No, there are no error message. It is just simply opening the index.js page in the text editor which is defined as the start page in the package.json file.